# Putting different types of references in natbib harvard style.

Tags: bibtex, natbib, harvard-style

I am using natbib and its agsm style for the harvard style reference formatting in my report. A sample would be like this.

```
Kivi, A. (2009), ‘Measuring mobile service usage: methods and measurement points’, 
International Journal of Mobile Communications 7(4), 415–435.
```

This works fine for different journal papers, conference papers, books etc. But I also want to add references to websites, white papers and other web resources. The problem is that these resources won't have a specific author attributed but mostly have the name of the organisation involved. Lets say Nokia, Ericsson, Facebook etc. Now how would I fit these types of references with the one above. They are ordered by the authors name and that too as Lastname, FirstnameAbbrv.

I want the bibliography entry to show the whole name of the organisation instead of this human name form. How would I do this? I want to know how to give the references for these different types of resources - websites, white papers, online resources etc.

Comment: I am not sure whether you question is about bibtex or referencing style... If you are just trying to get the name of the organisation not to be broken down and "scrambled" maybe you can try writing the name between curly brackets in your bibtex file (an extra pair of {} enclosing the name of the company)

Comment: @Vivi well my question was about how this particular natbib style showed the names of authors and your suggestions is exactly what I wanted to know. So thanks. If you would put this as an answer I would accept it :).

Comment: sure, I am glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to get the name of the organisation not to be broken down and "scrambled" maybe you can try writing the name between curly brackets in your bibtex file (an extra pair of {} enclosing the name of the company). This will tell TeX to write the name exactly as it is.

This trick also works when you don't want TeX to put upper cases or do the changes it usually does with the fields of a particular entry from your bib file.